# Merging requested tables in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to either merge or concatenate tables that I am generating through a loop in python. 
Here's what I have:

```
for i in [some_list]: 
    # replacing with the ith term to request that particular value
    url = "https://some_url/%s" % str(i)
    # accessing a table correspounding to my request 
    request = pd.read_html(url)[0] 
    #request1 is a table with the same columns as request
    request1 = request1.merge(request,how = 'outer') 
request1
```

Essentially I want to add on to my original request1 table which has the same columns as request table, However, I am getting an error: 
" You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat"

Comment: Whats is the error you are recieving?

Comment: You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `concat`

```
dflist=[]
for i in some_list:
    # replacing with the ith term to request that particular value
    url = "https://some_url/%s" % str(i)
    # accessing a table correspounding to my request
    request = pd.read_html(url)[0]
    dflist.append(pd.DataFrame(request))#Adding dataframe constructor here


request1=pd.concat(dflist)
```

Comment: `ignore_index=True` if OP cares about index.

Comment: Unfortunately, whenever I use an empty list the result returned is a list containing lists of my request. I want the returned result to be a stacked table of all the tables I have requested.

Comment: @NarekNersisyan check the update , I mask the line I change and left a comment